# How do I run a new Docker container and mount a host folder into a container folder on OSX?

Tags: macos, docker

I'm having issues completing step 4 (see image below) of the "Check container logs" exercise (7m:18s) in the 3rd video titled "Docker Operations" located under the docker [Self-Paced Training](https://training.docker.com/self-paced-training). For some reason I'm unable to mount the */container/logs/nginx/* folder and view the logs generated from nginx.

[image: Check container logs]

First, I created the folders */container/logs/nginx* under */Users/[username]* on my host machine and set the nginx folder permissions to *drwxrwxrwx* using the `sudo chmod ugo+rwx "nginx"` command.

Then, per the exercise I ran the following command `docker run -d -P -v /container/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx nginx`.

When I `cd /container/logs/nginx` and `ls` I'm not seeing the access.log or the error.log in the folder.

I'm not sure if this is a permissions issue or I've run the command incorrectly.

How do I run a new docker container and mount a host folder into a container folder on OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use `/container/logs/nginx` or `/Users/$USER/container/logs/nginx` both when creating a test directory and when pointing to it in the first part of the `docker -v`, otherwise those will be different directories.

Normally you don't need to set the permissions specially as long as you can write it there (according to my quick test), besides the id of the user `nginx` will most probably differ between your host macosx and at the docker instance.